# Why is this collection initializer trying to be static?

Tags: .net, collections, c#-4.0

I am trying to create a very simple list of entities that I am using for some unit tests I'm writing, but the compiler is complaining that I can't access an instance variable from a static context. So far as I can see, there are only instance variables.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using EMP.Domain.Entities;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace EMP.Domain.Tests.Repositories
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class AuditTrailRepositoryTests
    {
        private Guid orgId1 = Guid.NewGuid();

        private IList<AuditTrail> fakeAuditData = new List<AuditTrail>
                                                      {
                                                          new AuditTrail
                                                              {
                                                                  ChangeDate = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1),
                                                                  EntityName = "Test",
                                                                  OrganisationId = orgId1,
                                                                  Username = "admin"
                                                              }
                                                      };
    }
}
```

That is literally all the code in the class at this point. The compiler is complaining that

> Error 1   A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'EMP.Domain.Tests.Repositories.AuditTrailRepositoryTests.orgId1'

What is causing the `fakeAuditData` to think it's running in a static context? I've even added an instance method and been able to access both the collection and the Guids. So is the collection static when initialised and does this mean that it is only initialised once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't really related to collection-initializers per se; it's do with the fact that it in the provided sample, the collection-initializer is part of an *instance* field-initializer. These are not allowed to reference any instance members. From the language specification:

**10.5.5.2 Instance field initialization**

The instance field variable initializers of a class correspond to a sequence of assignments that are executed immediately upon entry to any one of the instance constructors (§10.11.1) of that class. The variable initializers are executed in the textual order in which they appear in the class declaration. The class instance creation and initialization process is described further in §10.11.

**A variable initializer for an instance field cannot reference the instance being created. Thus, it is a compile-time error to reference this in a variable initializer, as it is a compile-time error for a variable initializer to reference any instance member through a simple-name.**

Comment: But he is not referencing a type member of the instance being created.

Comment: `OrganisationId = orgId1`. There's an implicit `this.` there. It won't make a difference if this is added explicitly, it is still a compile-time error, albeit a different one.

Comment: @Ani: but what is the error then, if not being seen as a simple-name?

Comment: @leppie: Sorry, didn't understand the question. The field-initializer is accessing another field through a simple-name, no? If you make it explicit, you get a `Keyword 'this' is not available in the current context` error.

Comment: @Ani: Wait I get it now, same thing as referencing instance variables from a declaration's constructor  :)  Not really related to initializers.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [TestFixtureSetUp](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=fixtureSetup&r=2.2.10) to prepare the fake data for each unit test:

[TestFixture]

```
public class AuditTrailRepositoryTests
{
    private Guid orgId1;
    private IList<AuditTrail> fakeAuditData;

    [TestFixtureSetUp] 
    public void Init()
    {
        orgId1 = Guid.NewGuid();
        fakeAuditData = new List<AuditTrail>
        {
            new AuditTrail
            {
                ChangeDate = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1),
                EntityName = "Test",
                OrganisationId = orgId1,
                Username = "admin"
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I could, but I'm more curious about the behaviour of collection initializers generally, rather than specifically how to work around this issue for unit testing.

Comment: But this will result in the same error (if I understand the error correctly).

Answer (score 1):

The same reason why this is also a compile time error:

```
class Foo
{
  int a = 5;
  int b = a;
}
```